# How does Joi know what the wooden horse looks like?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In the scene with the DNA analyzer, she shows K what looks like the wooden horse but K will not fetch the horse until he goes to the scrapyard and finds it in the furnace. Is she able to somehow access K's memories? Or has he described it well enough for her to make this virtual copy?

I am rewatching the flick right now and somehow Joi shows K an apparently exact duplicate of the horse *before* K gets the physical object from the furnace at the scrapyard -- very puzzling.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that he's described it to JOI so often that she's been able to accurately reproduce it, possibly because he's repeatedly refined what she's showing him, in much the same way that Doctor Stelline uses her device to make 'micro-amendments'.

The stage direction in the [script](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf) says that she's conjured it from his memory but I think we can be reasonably sure that this means *from his description* of his memory.

> **K:** *There’s nothing to tell.*
>
> **JOI:** *How many times have you told me that story -- your memory. The date carved
> beneath.*
>
> IN JOI’S HAND IN FRONT OF K: JOI CONJURES THE TOY HORSE FROM K’S MEMORY. She shows the date carved under it: 6/10/21

Comment: Out-of-universe, it's probably because they decided to save a few dollars by not making a second, essentially identical prop

Comment: I'd have splurged on the second, non-matching prop because its being identical has puzzled at least one person. But it says, "conjures from K's memory" and perhaps Joi has mind-reading abilities similar to those of the device that the memory subcontractor uses.

Comment: @releseabe - The memory-reading device appears to be a cumbersome piece of equipment named after its inventor, the good doctor.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7_tZNMCpQ0